# R help, Getting my excel file loaded correctly

Tags: r, excel, statistics, t-test

I have written this line of code

```r
read_excel(path = "C:/users/irish/downloads/mis445googleamazonstock.xlsx", col_names = TRUE, col_types = NULL, na = "", skip = 0)
```

It pulls back the first ten lines of data, but I need to display 253 lines and three columns.

It says at the end to display further rows, use 'Print(n =.....)

I put in print(data, n=Inf) and it gave an error of Error in

```
print.default (x, usesource = usesource, ...): invalid na.print specifications.
```

I'm confused on what it's asking for. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Uploaded my excel file after downloading the read_excel package. Only received csome of my results.

Comment: (1) You need to capture the return value from that function, perhaps `dat <- read_excel(...)`. (2) Showing just the first 10 rows is normal (for many packages), if you want to see more than you would do `print(dat, n = 22)` or whatever.

Comment: See if this works: 
data <- read_excel(path = "C:/users/irish/downloads/mis445googleamazonstock.xlsx", col_names = TRUE, col_types = NULL, na = "", skip = 0)


 ; data[1:253, 1:3]

Answer (score 1):

I like to use the "readxl" library when opening excel spreadsheets.

Your code would look like:

```
library(readxl)

my_sheet <- read_excel("mis445googleamazonstock.xlsx")
```

1. Here is a link to help:
   http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/reading-data-from-excel-files-xls-xlsx-into-r
2. You can also use the built-in "Import Dataset" button under the environment tab

Comment: Thank you, I feel like I have an older version of this tool. I don't see an environment tab. When using the read_excel it says I don't have that function. Tried downloading and it's not going well. lol R is definitely above my pay grade here :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to view an object, you need to store it somewhere. You should try:

```
my_data <- read_excel("mis445googleamazonstock.xlsx")

print(my_data, n = 300)
```

RStudio is widely used as the best IDE for coding in `R`. If you’re using RStudio, you can view your whole dataset using:

```
View(my_data)
```